# Communication between Micro-services using Generic Object layer for Request and Responses

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I m designing a distributed system which is based on Spring boot and communication between them will be taken care by REST API calls.
Now number of services I have is greater than 8. I want to design a communication layer or a library common to all the services.

1. I want to use a generic request so all the services can understand and give response back in generic object layer.
2. The Generic Object can have field such as
   a. Request Payload; Timestamp; some identifiers for business use cases.
3. The Response can be appended to the same JSON Structure
   a. Request Payload; Timestamp; some identifiers for business use cases; Response Array with
   microservice name -- microservice response
4. Each microservice can add the response and this entire JSON object can be send further to any of the services, so each service can read and pull out the data it requires.

So basically, we will have an initial request and that request keeps on getting appended with various microservice reponses.

I m trying to avoid microservices sharing each others contract and becoming tightly coupled.

I need help to design the Generic Object. So do we have any Frameworks or Library which can help doing this ?
If any one has already tried the above approach how was experience ? Performance, Scalability, Maintenance, extendability and so on.

Since the request/response will be in JSON form, so keeping in mind loosely coupled contracts need to avoid JSON based Parsing errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you if I understand it correctly.
I highly suggest using Kafka.

**The object goes through REST calls.**

```
public class Bucket<T extends GenericResponse> implements Serializable {

    private Request triggeredActionRequest;


    //you can find your response for each micro by searching
    //and you can move on if one micro failed to add response.
    private Map<MicroNameEnum, T> responses;

    public Request getTriggeredActionRequest() {
        return triggeredActionRequest;
    }

    public void setTriggeredActionRequest(Request triggeredActionRequest) {
        this.triggeredActionRequest = triggeredActionRequest;
    }

    public Map<MicroNameEnum, T> getResponses() {
        return responses;
    }

    public void setResponses(Map<MicroNameEnum, T> responses) {
        this.responses = responses;
    }
}
```

**Response**

```
public class GenericResponse implements Serializable {
    private String absoluteJson;

    //You can add any fields you want,
// and every microservice will be aware of them without requiring explicit casting.


    public String getAbsoluteJson() {
        return absoluteJson;
    }

    public void setAbsoluteJson(String absoluteJson) {
        this.absoluteJson = absoluteJson;
    }
}
```

Enum

```
public enum MicroNameEnum {
    MICRO1("MICRO1"),
    MICRO2("MICRO2"),
    MICRO3("MICRO2"),
    MICRO4("MICRO4"),
    MICRO5("MICRO5"),
    MICRO6("MICRO6"),
    MICRO7("MICRO7"),
    MICRO8("MICRO8");


    private final String value;

    MicroNameEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This class only exists in your first microservice. If you want to use it in other microservices (if the absolute JSON is not sufficient for your needs), create a common project and inject it into your microservices.
**do not forget use super()**

```
public class MicroOneResponse extends GenericResponse implements Serializable {

    //this only exist in you micro one class.

    private Long idMicroOne;
    //any filed or data you want


    public Long getIdMicroOne() {
        return idMicroOne;
    }

    public void setIdMicroOne(Long idMicroOne) {
        this.idMicroOne = idMicroOne;
    }
}
```